# Hight CPU usage perf .net application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, profiling

I'm trying to profile my `.net` application written in `C#` which uses 100% of cpu. Application is very big, contains tons of code, so it is impossible to provide whole project code. I tried to get threads stack for application threads that uses 25% CPU (1 core), and often i got this:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2246
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x135e
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!KeStallWhileFrozen+0x1977
ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access+0x13f9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x152f
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xdd9
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x373
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xb2
ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x34a3
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x25b1f
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x25ad3
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x25a92
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x39106
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x39a81
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x394ad
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x39979
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x398c1
clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x3539a
clr.dll!ClrCreateManagedInstance+0x2747
KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

- Can anyone explain to me why thread with this call stack consumes 1 core
  of my CPU?
- What does this 'KeSynchronizeExecution'?
- How to avoid hight CPU usage in such situations?

Comment: The quality of this stack trace is very poor, when you want to see the soul of the machine then it is very important that you obtain the PDBs for the operating system. Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > tick "Microsoft Symbol Servers" and pick a symbol cache directory.  Fwiw, this trace does not show any decent hint of a perf problem, WaitForSingleObjectEx() is a synchronization function that blocks a thread. By far the best thing to do is to use a profiler so you can see the expensive code.

Answer (score 3):

Just trying to help you here, I am not an expert.

The **ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution** routine synchronizes the execution of the specified routine with the interrupt service routine (ISR) that is assigned to a set of one or more interrupt objects.

The **ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects** routine puts the current thread into an alertable or nonalertable wait state until any or all of a number of dispatcher objects are set to a signaled state or (optionally) until the wait times out.

The **ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject** routine puts the current thread into an alertable or nonalertable wait state until the given mutex object is set to a signaled state or (optionally) until the wait times out.

I think **ntoskrnl.exe!KEStallWhileFrozen** routine is called when waits for multiple objects routines are not resolved.

**ntoskrnl.exe!_misaligned_access** routine is an alert when cpu cannot read misaligned data. Seems *Misaligned memory accesses can incur enormous performance losses on targets that do not support them in hardware*. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253949(v=vs.80).aspx. Also check the Avoiding Alignment Errors section.

**ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject** waits until the specified object attains a state of signaled.

A call to the **setjmp** function saves the current instruction address as well as other CPU registers. A subsequent call to the **longjmp** function restores the instruction pointer and registers, and execution resumes at the point just after the setjmp call.

**ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject** routine waits until the specified object attains a state of Signaled. An optional time-out can also be specified.

**KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx** waits until the specified object is in the signaled state, an I/O completion routine or asynchronous procedure call (APC) is queued to the thread, or the time-out interval elapses.

**clr.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterface** gets a pointer to an internal interface instance that is used to read and write metadata in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jetbrains solution before for this. And it could really find optimization points easy. My advice use : https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ and find which process and methods high usage cpu. also you can find memory etc.

I know you can install it trial. Install it trial and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just saw a similar problem in my application.
I was able to profile it using [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) application.
In my case it was lock inside Dictionary.Insert method. Trying to access dictionary from multiple threads at the same time causes infinit operations in these threads.
Looks like one CPU Core goes to 25% usage and no chance to unlock it.